# GetText() clarification - xpath not returning the value

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, xpath

Html:

```
<strong class="text-xl ng-binding" ng-bind="summary.PublishedIssuedRecent">5</strong>
```

my xpath:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//strong[@ng-bind='summary.PublishedIssuedRecent']")
public WebElement countRecentlyPublishedApplication;

String pubCount = countRecentlyPublishedApplication.getText();
```

my Expectation

i want to extract the value of `5`

but i'm getting empty value in the `pubCount` String, Please suggest if any mistake in my xpath

Comment: I assume you are using Selenium, right? If so, please add the respective tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From attribute `ng-bind` I'm guessing you're trying to scrap angularJS application and you're using selenium web driver.

Problem with angular is, it is rendered by javascript after the page loads. So on beginning element you want to scrap might not be there. Solution might be to wait a second until angulars finishes rendering and then try to find element.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement pubCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//strong[@ng-bind='summary.PublishedIssuedRecent']")).getText();
```

Comment: yes , the xpath correct, issue in rendering time,thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression in itself is correct, it selects your node as expected. A simple test with `xmllint` gives:

```
> xmllint --xpath "//strong[@ng-bind='summary.PublishedIssuedRecent']" ~/test.html
<strong class="text-xl ng-binding" ng-bind="summary.PublishedIssuedRecent">5</strong>
```

So the error is outside your XPath expression.

By the way, if you just need the text of the node, you can use

```
> xmllint --xpath "//strong[@ng-bind='summary.PublishedIssuedRecent']/text()" ~/test.html
5
```